# AWS Kinesis Firehose data appended together when delivering to AWS Redshift

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, amazon-kinesis-firehose

I'm triggering a lambda to send data to Redshift through Firehose. When the lambda is triggered twice within a small period of time, say 1 minute, the data is collated. This creates an issue in loading the data to redshift and the issue is "Extra column(s) found".

eg: 1st set of data: 1,2,3,4, 2nd set of data: 5,6,7,8. Data received by Redshift: 1,2,3,45,6,7,8

After this happens, even if lambda is triggered once, no data is loaded into Redshift.

Why is this happening? How can I avoid this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is likely due to omitting the end-of-record character from your data injecting code.  End-of-record is  unless changed and this indicates that this is all the data for the record.  You need to have a  in your data stream.

This isn't a problem when the data comes in further apart in time because firehose only waits a fixed amount of time before sending the data it has to Redshift.  In this case end-of-file is reach and end-of-record is assumed.